# What is the biblical justification for allowing only male pastors?

Tags: bible, women, ministry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the biblical justification for permitting female pastors?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/114/what-is-the-biblical-justification-for-permitting-female-pastors)

What is the biblical justification for allowing *only* male pastors?

How do churches excluding women from pastoral and teaching roles justify their stance as The Christian Way?

Comment: If you are willing to overlook certain passages, you could have women pastors.

Comment: @Richard There are many, many christian churches that believe only men should be pastors. I want to know how they support this idea from their christian religion (without looking to argue). How is it narrow or localised?

Comment: Actually, [that question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/114/what-is-the-biblical-justification-for-permitting-female-pastors) comes from the presupposition that being allowing female pastors is wrong.  The question itself answers this question.  I'll post that below.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate as it asks the basis for the opposing position.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[1Timothy 2:12-14 (NASB)](http://biblia.com/books/nasb95/1Ti2.12-14) says pretty clearly that women shouldn't be pastors:

> **12** But I do not allow a woman to teach or exercise authority over a
>   man, but to remain quiet.
>
> **13** For it was Adam who was first created, and then Eve.
>
> **14** And it was not Adam who was deceived, but the woman being
>   deceived, fell into transgression.

Comment: It's from [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/114/what-is-the-biblical-justification-for-permitting-female-pastors)

Comment: Right. And from Hebrews 13:17 we know that a preacher is someone with authority.

Comment: @RichardHas anyone brought up the fact that Jesus only ordained MALE APOSTLES, and that when Judas was replaced, they looked for a Man who had accompanied Jesus for the 31/2 years. (Acts 1:21-22)...Also the synagogues which were a pattern for the Early Church only had male elders...and has anyone considered the CULTURAL DRIFT phenomenon caused by "feminism" in modern times? {This topic was not allowed on #114 question.}

Answer (score 4):

The verse I always was referred to on this subject is
I Corinthians 14:34-35 (NLT)

> 34 Women should be silent during the church meetings. It is not proper for them to speak. They should be submissive, just as the law says.
>
> 35 If they have any questions, they should ask their husbands at home, for it is improper for women to speak in church meetings.

Comment: @SamuelWarrenThe Bible listed the qualifications for any "Overseer" in 1 Tim. 3:1-7, and Titus 1:5-9. It always uses the masculine when referencing this.  It said, "husband of one wife", not "wife of one husband." But it must be pointed out that Paul expressed great indebtedness to women who worked in the Church in Romans 16! (See the list.) They were an irreplaceable asset to the spread of the Gospel...as they are today! There are many "supernatural charismatic gifts" available to them, and they have ministries that only they can do, that men can't.  We are complimentary, if not hierarchical.